# Could you safely say this code is "unsafe"

Tags: c#, pinvoke

this is the calss that implements native pinvok code

Code That seem to work though i could not verify it is using unsafe properly

signeture with unsafe

```
    struct IO_COUNTERS
    {
        public ulong ReadOperationCount;
        public ulong WriteOperationCount;
        public ulong OtherOperationCount;
        public ulong ReadTransferCount;
        public ulong WriteTransferCount;
        public ulong OtherTransferCount;
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    unsafe static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr* ProcessHandle, out IO_COUNTERS IoCounters);
```

code with my "unsafe"

```
        public static unsafe class IO
        {
            public static Dictionary<string, ulong> GetALLIO(Process procToRtrivIO)
            {
                IO_COUNTERS counters;
                Dictionary<string, ulong> retCountIoDict = new Dictionary<string, ulong>();
                GetProcessIoCounters((IntPtr*)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out counters);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadOperationCount", counters.ReadOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteOperationCount", counters.WriteOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherOperationCount", counters.OtherOperationCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("ReadTransferCount", counters.ReadTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("WriteTransferCount", counters.WriteTransferCount);
                retCountIoDict.Add("OtherTransferCount", counters.OtherTransferCount);
                return retCountIoDict;
                //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
                //    " Mb of data.";

            }
        }
```

now this next block of code, was suggested in my other question (just before i managed to compile and run the code above, ...as i had some issues with it )

so just after i have solevd my question through trial and error someone posted this partial solution, and it is parital cause it does not include both 
`struct` and `signeture`, so i was asking if it was being tested cause it does compile but does not run .
i mean when it runs(with no compliation error) but on run time, the error is

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Code.1ri3mog1.dll but was not handled in user code
```

**Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

so this is the code i got from my last question

```
Ok you need to change a few things, shown below

public static class IO
{
    unsafe public static Dictionary<string, ulong> GetALLIO(Process procToRtrivIO)
    {
        IO_COUNTERS* counters;
        Dictionary<string, ulong> retCountIoDict = new Dictionary<string, ulong>();
        IntPtr ptr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

        GetProcessIoCounters(&ptr, out counters);
        retCountIoDict.Add("ReadOperationCount", counters->ReadOperationCount);
        retCountIoDict.Add("WriteOperationCount", counters->WriteOperationCount);
        retCountIoDict.Add("OtherOperationCount", counters->OtherOperationCount);
        retCountIoDict.Add("ReadTransferCount", counters->ReadTransferCount);
        retCountIoDict.Add("WriteTransferCount", counters->WriteTransferCount);
        retCountIoDict.Add("OtherTransferCount", counters->OtherTransferCount);
        return retCountIoDict;
        //return  "This process has read " + ((counters.ReadTransferCount/1024)/1024).ToString("N0") +
        //    " Mb of data.";

    }
}
```

so question is , did i truely make it... and safely used an unsafe code (the top block of code ) 
or i have missed something, and if my code is ok(still i suspect it is not fully using unsafe fitures) , what is wrong with the suggested version of code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is badly broken. Your declaration of `GetProcessIoCounters` is wrong. You are passing the address of the process handle but you need to pass the process handle by value. What's more there is no need at all for `unsafe` code here. I suggest you stop using `unsafe`.

Here's how you declare `GetProcessIoCounters`:

```
[DllImport(@"kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(
    IntPtr hProcess, 
    out IO_COUNTERS IoCounters
);
```

Your declaration of `IO_COUNTERS` is fine.

To call the function you simply do this:

```
IO_COUNTERS IoCounters;
if (!GetProcessIoCounters(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out IoCounters))
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

Comment: hey thanks for the code cause i realy forgot how it was without the unsafe already , though the task was not to use the .net own classes to aquire that info, so i could gain some performance atleast test if and how much did i get out of this p/invoke implementation , then i said to my self, ok let's go even further and test p/invoke plus unsafe then just p/invoke and back to .net cause i might use p/invoke if it will show some good performance gain but i am not sure as to using unsafe on regular bases , though just for my test i was trying to .

Comment: Using unsafe won't make this code faster. There's no point in using unsafe here.

Comment: ok then just add the "bool" in signature and it's a signed deal (:

Comment: yes it happens when your brains is quicker than your fingers by a small margin (: i guess i am far from being a programmer but i could atleast be a good typo qa..(: thanks alot for stopping by .